# Graph API shows only past events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just came back from a three months break of programming.

Before leaving `id/events` would return any events (past and future) of a facebook page.

Now `id/events/?limit=10&since=2018-08-02` returns a empty array or only one event whereas a lot of events are upcoming

Has something changed in the API or it is a setting from the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only Events for which the requesting User is listed as a Host or Guest
>   will be returned.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/page/events